# Lagged time series analysis

Tags: causality, cross-correlation

Given 3 continuous, normally distributed, independent, time-series vectors (**X**, **Y**, **Z**) and 1 continuous, Poisson distributed, dependant, time-series vector (**A**). How can I rank the independent vectors in terms of how much they influence (**A**)? Baring in mind there will be a delay (lag), of an unknown time period, in changes **X**, **Y**, **Z** causing changes in **A**.

My initial thought was cross-correlation, but I'm struggling to evaluate my results to determine which vector has the most influence and whether that influence is significant.